# How can I access an object's property in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My user object has a boolean property that I want to check as a user logs in.

This is what I'm trying to do, but I am getting a 500 error:

```
user = User.find_by_email(params['email'])
if user.is_mentor
    #do something
end
```

Comment: What if the user is not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check to see if there was actually a user that was found with the email `params['email']`:

```
user = User.find_by_email params['email']

if user.present? && user.is_mentor?
    # do something
end
```

Here, `user.present?` checks to see if `user` is not equal to nil, which is what it would be if no user was found.

Also, the `?` at the end of a method call indicates that the method is returning a boolean value. You should include the question mark in the method call as well if the method is user defined:

```
def is_mentor?
    # do something
end
```

Comment: Yup! That is a shorthand way to write the if statement I wrote. The `&.` is called the safe navigation operator in Ruby, and it was introduced in ruby 2.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a check to see if you found an user

```
if user.is_a?(User) && user.is_mentor
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to check that the user exists first:

```
if user && user.is_mentor?
    # do something
end
```

user will be nil and false if Rails didn't find the user.